# Wildfly Server is failing in non windows environment and with error WFLYCTL0017 && WFLYCTL0013

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, redhat, keycloak

I'm passing a few commands with ProcessBuilder(JAVA) to standalone.sh.
When I'm running in a windows environment with standalone.bat with the same argument just path has been taken care it's able to run in Windows.

But when I'm trying same code with mac or RedHat Linux it's getting failed.

And I'm not able to see it in log files as its getting failed before starting the server.

I have tried comparing both standalone.xml from windows and MAC both are identical.

For Mac which it's failing

```
  JBOSS_HOME: /Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Diam.keystore.password=\${VAULT::IAM::IAM_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD::1} -DIAM_HOME=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/ -Diam.db.password=\${VAULT::IAM::IAM_DB_PASSWORD::1} -Diam.db.jdbc.driver.path=/Users/ajay/driveD/software/jars/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar -Diam.vault.enc.iteration.count=120 -Diam.db.vendor=mssql -Diam.vault.keystore.password.masked=MASK-7DscHYCAzRJgjgpBba72IwRGfBaq4CFF70uETVutVDX -Diam.truststore.password=\${VAULT::IAM::IAM_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD::1} -Diam.db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://ibndev000608.bpc.broadcom.net:1433;databaseName=IAM105_VAULT -Diam.keystore=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks -Diam.vault.keystore.salt=6zqH6N6p -Diam.truststore=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/iam-truststore.ks -Diam.vault.enc.file.dir=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/vault/ -Diam.vault.keystore.alias=vault -Diam.vault.keystore.url=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/vault/vault.keystore -Diam.db.user=sa -Djboss.http.port=51112 -Djboss.https.port=51111 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=iam-updater -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=../realms-to-import -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING -Diam.version=1.2.1-SNAPSHOT -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

And the Error I'm getting is 
./standalone.sh: line 311: -Diam.keystore=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks: No such file or directory

Even webreckeys.ks this file is in place and all permission is there.

```
=========================================================================

Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
./standalone.sh: line 311: -Diam.keystore=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks: No such file or directory
```

For windows, it's able to run

```
 JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\PROGRA~1\CA\IAM_10_5\IDENTI~1"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat  -Diam.keystore.password=${VAULT::IAM::IAM_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD::1} -DIAM_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\CA\IAM_10_5\IDENTI~1\ -Diam.db.password=${VAULT::IAM::IAM_DB_PASSWORD::1} -Diam.db.jdbc.driver.path=D:\setups\10.5\sqljdbc4-4.0.jar -Diam.vault.enc.iteration.count=120 -Diam.db.vendor=mssql -Diam.vault.keystore.password.masked=MASK-7DscHYCAzRJgjgpBba72IwRGfBaq4CFF70uETVutVDX -Diam.truststore.password=${VAULT::IAM::IAM_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD::1} -Diam.db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://ibndev000608.bpc.broadcom.net:1433;databaseName=LocalWindowsIAM10_5 -Diam.keystore=C:\PROGRA~1\CA\IAM_10_5\IDENTI~1\certs/webreckeys.ks -Diam.vault.keystore.salt=6zqH6N6p -Diam.truststore=C:\PROGRA~1\CA\IAM_10_5\IDENTI~1\certs/iam-truststore.ks -Diam.vault.enc.file.dir=C:\PROGRA~1\CA\IAM_10_5\IDENTI~1\vault/ -Diam.vault.keystore.alias=vault -Diam.vault.keystore.url=C:\PROGRA~1\CA\IAM_10_5\IDENTI~1\vault/vault.keystore -Diam.db.user=sa -Djboss.http.port=51112 -Djboss.https.port=51111 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=iam-updater -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=../realms-to-import -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING -Diam.version=1.2.1-SNAPSHOT -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

After enabling the logging level to DEBUG

I could see few errors

```
2019-09-23 12:18:55,175 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0017: Operation ("read-resource") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mssql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"jdbc-driver\" => \"mssql\")
]' not found"
```

And Other one is

```
2019-09-17 17:06:00,607 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("list-resource-loader-paths") failed - address: ([("core-service" => "module-loading")]) - failure description: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc"
```

And Here is subsytem tag in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>${iam.db.url}</connection-url>
                    <driver>mssql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>${iam.db.user}</user-name>
                        <password>${iam.db.password}</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mssql" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
                        <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: The file isn't there or isn't accessable.  Can you do a `ls -l /Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks`?

Comment: @stdunbar I have mentioned all the read-write permission is there and file as well in the correct place.

```
C02Z45LWLVDR:~ ajay$ ls -l /Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ajay  admin  1396 May 14 09:50 /Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks
C02Z45LWLVDR:~ ajay$
```

Comment: @stdunbar I have updated with debug log finding could you please have a look and suggest why it's happenings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, why it was failing and misleading with error msg.

The cause was with -
`Diam.db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://ibndev000608.bpc.broadcom.net:1433;databaseName=IAM105_VAULT`

In the value of -Diam.db.url   is having a semicolon `jdbc:sqlserver://ibndev000608.bpc.broadcom.net:1433;databaseName=IAM105_VAULT`

and after semicolon `databaseName=IAM105_VAULT`

And next after keystore command was there

`-databaseName=IAM105_VAULT -Diam.keystore=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks`

so It's became like

`databaseName=IAM105_VAULT -Diam.keystore=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks`

And in Linux and Mac environment semicolon means separator between two commands.

How did I troubleshoot is

I opened standalone.sh and place at first line   `set -x` which means trace the shell script.

And it's shown two commands so I identified and enclosed JDBC URL in  double quotes (" ")

```
-Diam.db.url="jdbc:sqlserver://ibndev000608.bpc.broadcom.net:1433;databaseName=IAM105_VAULT" -Diam.keystore=/Applications/CA/10.5SQLSERVER/IdentityAccessManager/certs/webreckeys.ks
```

And it's work for me... 
thanks for all your effort guys.

Comment: Good investigation ! You can accept your own answer, it might help people encountering the same problem in the future in finding your solution. BTW if you don't want to edit a script to add `set -x` inside it you can also launch it with `bash -x`, e.g. `bash -x standalone.sh` for the same effect as `set -x`

Answer (score 0):

How about other files like truststore, if thats picking then there must be problem with keystore file location or may be name of it. For verification you can check your keystore file by placing it in location of your jboss-home and give that specific path in JAVA_OPTS, if it works then certainly problem with file location or may file path. Also take caution while using '/'  symbol.

Comment: I have updated with debug log could you please have a look, I'm stuck here.